# Error while reading data from dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [my todo application here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/58/), I am unable to read data from a dynamically generated `<textarea>` at the second attempt. In the first attempt I can read it correctly.

You can edit the task by just clicking on it. At the first attempt, it works properly and the `localStorage` is updated. But, when we try to edit the same item again, its reading it as `undefined`. And hence an error is thrown:

```
Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

Its at this line:

```
if($("#new_data").val().toLowerCase() === item[0].toLowerCase()){  // line # 263
```

One of these two ^ have the value as `undefined` for some reason.

What am I missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/58/)

**EDIT:**
*Recreating the issue*: Add a new item > edit it to something else > click somewhere else so it saves > now edit it again to something else and click somewhere else again > There should be an error in the console. 
I am using Chrome v35.

Comment: `#new_data` probably doesn't exist yet. That or `item[0]` is undefined.

Comment: `#new_data` exists since its the value in the textarea and `item[0]` exists too, since its read from the `localStorage` that has valid data.

Comment: apparently not, since otherwise you wouldn't be getting this error. there are only a few occations when .val returns undefined.

Comment: Correction, there's only one case where .val() will return undefined: when the element doesn't exist. Clearly `$("#new_data")` is selecting 0 elements.

Comment: also.... i can't seem to recreate your issue.

Comment: @KevinB To recreate the issue, add a new item, edit it, click somewhere else so it saves, now edit it again and click somewhere else again. There should be an error in the console. I am using Chrome v35.

Comment: If you watch the console, you will see events triggering way more than expected. Looks like you may be incorrectly binding events inside of events. According to the console, it correctly found a value 4 times, and then failed on the 5th, even though i only edited it twice.

Comment: the problem originates here: `$(document).on("focusout enter", "#new_data", function(){` You're executing that more than once. Each time you execute it, the event handler will trigger that many more times per event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be attaching a new delegated event handler to `"focusout enter"` for `#new_data` every time you call `editItem()`.

The first event handler will work fine, but the second (or possibly third, fourth, etc.) will always throw the `undefined` exception, since the first handler will have already destroyed the `#new_data` element with this line:

```
$(element).find('textarea')
          .replaceWith("<p class='item_content'>"+$("#new_data").val()+"</p>");
```

There's a couple of ways you can tackle this:

A) Pull the whole event binding out of the editItem function, and only ever call it once:

```
function editItem() { /* do stuff */ }
$(document).on("focusout enter", "#new_data", function(){ /* do stuff */ });
```

B) Name the event handler and call `.off` before you bind a new one:

```
            function focusOutHandler(){ /* do stuff */ }
            $(document).off("focusout enter", "#new_data", focusOutHandler)
                       .on("focusout enter", "#new_data", focusOutHandler);
```

And C) My personal favourite -- **don't delegate it**

```
 $(element).find('textarea').on("focusout enter", function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/5Z67W/